# png images does not load with ios 5.1

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator

I have few **png images** in my App and and i have placed it in the **UIImageView** of xib but the problem is the images loads fine with **ios 6.0** simulator but the images are not visible in **ios 5.1 simulator** and my **Xcode version is 4.5** same with my devices in ipad 3 it loads fine and ipad 1 it is invisible any problem with image resolutions

Comment: please check for the name , can you post the code you use to map images.

Comment: i am directly setting it in the Image field of UIImageView from xib

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add it with extension:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```